# How to design a good RESTFul web api which involves two objects?

Tags: rest, restful-url

I'd like  to know how to design a good RESTFul api which involves two or more objects?For example,it's easy to design a api for getting a book's info as well as getting an anthor's info , like `/book/1` and `/anthor/1`,but how about getting all books for an anthor?
1.`author/{author_id}/books`
2.`books/get_by_author?author_id=1`
3.`books/search?author_id=1`
which one is better? Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it really depends on your use case.
If you're trying to provide a search functionality on books with a limited search criteria, I would go with something like

```
GET books?author_id=1&genre=fiction
```

If your search criteria will grow in the future, I would recommend a POST API like so

```
POST books/search
{
   "author_id": 1,
   "genre": "fiction",
   "year": 2012
}
```

However, if you're always going to try and fetch the books "only" for a specific author, go with

```
authors/<author_id>/books
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is a good option. Use authors instead of author. Your URL will look like this:

/author**s**/{author_id}/books